# Show that there are infinitely many positive roots of $\frac{-e^{x}}{2}(1+f(x))+\frac{e^{-x}}{2}(1-f(x))+f(x)\cos x+\sin x=0$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I am trying to show algebraically that there are infinitely many positive roots of the equation $$\frac{-e^{x}}{2}(1+f(x))+\frac{e^{-x}}{2}(1-f(x))+f(x)\cos x+\sin x=0,$$

where $f(x)=-\left(\frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x - \sin x}\right).$ I can see that the roots are approximately the values $x \approx n \pi$ graphically. Indeed, substituting $x = n \pi$ into the above equation gives $f(x)=-1$ and thus the $e^x$ and $\sin x$ terms vanish, and we get a value that tends to $\pm1$, which, given the large derivative of the function at these points, shows this is a good approximation of the root.

I am not sure how to verify algebraically that there are infinitely many - I know the asymptotes of the function are when $\cos x = \sin x \implies x = m \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is continuous everywhere so I am thinking to use the intermediate value theorem, but I can't seem to find good end points where the function gives a positive number for one value and a negative number for the other.

[image: Graph of the above function in Desmos. Roots appear to be at approximately x = n \pi for all n.]

I have tried to manipulate the equation and have simplified it to get

$$e^{-x}(\cos^2x-\cos x \sin x)-e^x(\cos x \sin x -\sin^2x)=1$$

although this does not seem to help, and more problematically has introduced more roots.

Answer (score 1):

If I‘m not wrong, the equation is equivalent to (ignoring the points where the denominator is zero)
$$(\cos x+ \sin x)e^{-x}=1.$$
This has infinitely many negative solutions, but only finitely many positives.